# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to learn to use native code in android studio. However, I am encountering an error when I try to calling a native function that returns an integer value and pass it to my java class. I get this error 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.mobi.MainActivity.randomintFromJNI() (tried Java_com_mobi_MainActivity_randomintFromJNI)
What could I be doing wrong ?

```
package com.mobi;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Example of a call to a native method
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

            tv.setText(Integer.toString(randomintFromJNI()));
        }

        /**
         * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
         * which is packaged with this application.
         */
        public native String stringFromJNI();
        public native static int randomintFromJNI();

    }

c++
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_mobi_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    string hello = "Hello from C++";

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}


JNIEXPORT jint

JNICALL
Java_com_mobi_MainActivity_randomintFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    int val = rand()*100;

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing an extern "C" on Java_com_mobi_MainActivity_randomintFromJNI